# VSCode fail to install C/C++ extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

Error message looks like this:

```
Updating C/C++ dependencies...

Downloading package 'C/C++ language components (Windows)' 
Failed at stage: downloadPackages
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\AppData\Local\Temp\package-16480SeUxcb3yzPVb'
```

Problem is, disk volume E was my old disk volume, and that HDD was physically broken. I replaced another physical HDD, and created volumes F,G,H instead, but NOT E any more.

And, I've checked

```
C:\Users\ooCast>echo %USERPROFILE%
C:\Users\ooCast

C:\Users\ooCast>echo %APPDATA%
C:\Users\ooCast\AppData\Roaming
```

They are not E as well.

Re-installing VS Code doesn't fix the problem. I guess it's some REG entry persists this value, but not sure which one is it.